# Attempting to post data serialized using Protocol Buffers fails when serializing

Tags: asp.net, serialization, protobuf-net, protocol-buffers

### In Brief

When attempting to serialize an object using Google's Protocol Buffers I get the following error:

> Type is not expected, and no contract can be inferred:

### More Detail

I have three projects:

1. DotNet Standard 2.0 Library project with a *.proto file
2. DotNet Framework 4.8 WebAPI
3. DotNet 5 Test application

#### DotNet Standard 2.0 Library project with a *.proto file

The Library contains a *.proto file.  This contains several different `message` objects, each with properties that are either strings or int32.  There's two "wrapper" objects, one named `Request` (and the other `Response`).  There's nothing obviously complicated.

The NuGet packages for this Library are:

```
<PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf" Version="3.17.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Grpc" Version="2.40.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Grpc.Tools" Version="2.40.0">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

It may be that some aren't necessary....

#### DotNet Framework 4.8 WebAPI

So the idea is that my .NET 4.8 WebAPI will receive the `Request` object (that is one of these classes defined in the proto file) and then return the `Response` object (also defined in this proto file).

#### DotNet 5 Test application

However....my test is failing before it even gets the chance to make the Http call to the WebAPI...

My .NET 5 Test project has the following NuGet package:

```
<PackageReference Include="protobuf-net" version="3.0.101" />
```

It also has a package reference to my .NET Standard library (so knows about `Request` and `Response`, and the NuGet packages that it has.

In my test I create a new `Request` object (from the namespace `SomeNamespace` defined in the proto file) and populate it's properties.

I then attempt to serialize it using:

```
using MemoryStream stream = new();
ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize<Request>(stream, objectToBeSerialized);
```

And that's where the error occurs:

> System.InvalidOperationException
> HResult=0x80131509
> Message=Type is not expected, and no contract can be inferred: SomeNamespace.Request
> Source=protobuf-net.Core
> StackTrace:
> at ProtoBuf.Internal.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(String message, Exception innerException) in /*/src/protobuf-net.Core/Internal/ThrowHelper.cs:line 56
> at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.ThrowUnexpectedType(Type type, TypeModel model) in /*/src/protobuf-net.Core/Meta/TypeModel.cs:line 1648
> at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.SerializeRootFallback(State& state, Object value) in /*/src/protobuf-net.Core/Meta/TypeModel.cs:line 282
> at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.SerializeImpl[T](State& state, T value) in /*/src/protobuf-net.Core/Meta/TypeModel.cs:line 358
> at ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize[T](Stream destination, T instance, Object userState) in /*/src/protobuf-net/Serializer.Serialize.cs:line 33
> at ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize[T](Stream destination, T instance) in /*/src/protobuf-net/Serializer.Serialize.cs:line 20
> at TestNamespace.TempTests.d__0.MoveNext() in c:\SomePath\TempTests.cs:line 53

I'm not clear why this might be failing.

**Ideally**, I'd like to standardise on best practices, so if I'm not using the ideal NuGet packages then please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In protobuf, when working with a .proto, there are two sets of tools involved:

1. the schema parser/code generator
2. the runtime library

Now, what we *also* need to know is that there are multiple implementations of protobuf in .NET-land; relevant to this question, there is the Google implementation, and protobuf-net (there are others, but they don't relate to this question).

What I think you've done is: you've used the Google tools for step 1 ("protoc") but protobuf-net for step 2. The tools for 1 and 2 need to match: Google and Google is fine; protobuf-net and protobuf-net is fine - but not crossovers.

So, either:

a. use the Google runtime library instead of protobuf-net ("Google.Protobuf", as a nuget package), or
b: use protobuf-net's schema tools and code gen (see https://protobuf-net.github.io/protobuf-net/contract_first.html, including the links at the bottom for other options)

If I'm right in my hunch, please let me know - I'll try to make protobuf-net recognize this scenario and at least offer suitable guidance

Comment: Spot on Marc!  I limited the NuGet packages in both the Library and Test projects to just the three Google ones (see post above), then did `byte[] byteArray = objectToBeSerialized.ToByteArray();` then `ByteArrayContent byteContent = new(byteArray);` then `byteContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/octet-stream");` and finally a `PostAsync` on my HttpClient.